# Failed to execute goal jbpm-console-ng-showcase error=206 filename or extension is too long

Tags: jboss, maven-3, jbpm

i am trying to develop jbpm6 using maven..i am using maven 3.0.5 version in windows platform.i used https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng link to get the source code.when i try to "mvn clean install" in most of modules in my project they build successfully.
but in one module i have problems face...
when i try to "mvn clean install" it, it gives below error,

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (gwt-compile) @ jbpm-console-ng-showcase ---
[WARNING] Declared compileSourcesArtifact was not found in project dependencies org.drools:drools-wb-workitems-editor-api:jar
[WARNING] Declared compileSourcesArtifact was not found in project dependencies org.drools:drools-wb-workitems-editor-client:jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.465s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 30 12:48:31 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 66M/474M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (gwt-compile) on project jbpm-console-ng-showcase: Failed to execute command line :
[ERROR] [-Xmx2048m, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -Djetty.custom.sys.classes=bitronix;javax.transaction, -Dorg.kie.demo=true, -Dorg.kie.clean.onstartup=true, -classpath, C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.5.0\gwt-user-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.5.0\
gwt-dev-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\workspace\jbpm-console-ng-r6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-showcase\target\classes;C:\Users\AKILA\workspace\jbpm-console-ng-r6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-showcase\src\main\java;C:\Users\AKILA\workspace\jbpm-console-ng-r6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-showcase\src\main\resourc
es;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-ci\6.0.1.Final\kie-ci-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-core\6.0.1.Final\drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-compiler\6.0.1.Final\drools-compiler-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repo
sitory\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.5\antlr-runtime-3.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\3.7.2\ecj-3.7.2.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-core\3.0.5\maven-core-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings\3.0.5\maven-
settings-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings-builder\3.0.5\maven-settings-builder-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-repository-metadata\3.0.5\maven-repository-metadata-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-arti
let\jse\org.restlet\2.1.4\org.restlet-2.1.4.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-commons\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-commons-0.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA
\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-jboss-as-support\2.4.3.Final\errai-jboss-as-support-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-bus\2.4.3.Final\errai-bus-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-config\2.4.3.Final\errai-config-2.4.3.Final.jar;
C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-marshalling\2.4.3.Final\errai-marshalling-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\javass
ist\javassist\3.15.0-GA\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\io\netty\netty\4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1\netty-4.0.0.Alpha1.errai.r1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\13.0.1\guava-13.0.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jgroups\jgroups\3.2.10.Fin
al\jgroups-3.2.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc\2.4.3.Final\errai-ioc-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen\2.4.3.Final\errai-codegen-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-codegen-gwt\2.4.3.Final\
errai-codegen-gwt-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-client\2.4.3.Final\errai-cdi-client-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ioc-bus-support\2.4.3.Final\errai-ioc-bus-support-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\
errai\errai-javax-enterprise\2.4.3.Final\errai-javax-enterprise-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-weld-integration\2.4.3.Final\errai-weld-integration-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-cdi-jetty\2.4.3.Final\errai-cdi-jetty-2.4.3.Fina
l.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-ui\2.4.3.Final\errai-ui-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.7.1\jsoup-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\stanbol\org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.htmlextractor\0.10.0\org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.
engines.htmlextractor-0.10.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\clerezza\rdf.core\0.12-incubating\rdf.core-0.12-incubating.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\clerezza\utils\0.1-incubating\utils-0.1-incubating.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.
1\httpcore-4.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\wymiwyg\wymiwyg-commons-core\0.7.6\wymiwyg-commons-core-0.7.6.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging-api\1.1\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\lesscss\lesscss\1.3.3\lesscss-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\
AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mozilla\rhino\1.7R4\rhino-1.7R4.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\errai\errai-data-binding\2.4.3.Final\errai-data-binding-2.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\goog
le\guava\guava-gwt\14.0.1\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.3.168\h2-1.3.168.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.2.0.SP1\hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.SP1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.
2.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.2.GA.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\
hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.2.0.SP1\hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibern
ate-validator\4.3.1.Final\hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty\6.1.25\jetty-6.1.25.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.
1.25\jetty-util-6.1.25.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\servlet-api\2.5-20081211\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-plus\6.1.25\jetty-plus-6.1.25.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-naming\6.1.25\jetty-naming-6.
1.25.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\se\weld-se-core\1.1.13.Final\weld-se-core-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-spi\1.1.Final\weld-spi-1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-api\1.1.Final\weld-api-1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKIL
A\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-core\1.1.13.Final\weld-core-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-ext\1.7.2\slf4j-ext-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\ch\qos\cal10n\cal10n-api\0.7.4\cal10n-api-0.7.4.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javax\el\el-api\2.2\el-api-2.2
.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\servlet\weld-servlet-core\1.1.13.Final\weld-servlet-core-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\solder\solder-impl\3.2.1.Final\solder-impl-3.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3.RC2\hamcrest-cor
e-1.3.RC2.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\solder\solder-logging\3.2.1.Final\solder-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.5.0\gwt-user-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources
.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\osgi\org.osgi.core\4.2.0\org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.5\jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-xjc\2.2.5\jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\
jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\btm\btm\2.1.4\btm-2.1.4.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-shared-services\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-shared-services-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-persistence-jpa\6.0.1.Final\drools-persistence-jpa-6
.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-bpmn2-emfextmodel\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-bpmn2-emfextmodel-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\emf\org.eclipse.emf.common\2.6.0.v20100614-1136\org.eclipse.emf.common-2.6.0.v20100614-1136.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\
eclipse\emf\org.eclipse.emf.ecore\2.6.0.v20100614-1136\org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.6.0.v20100614-1136.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\emf\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi\2.5.0.v20100521-1846\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.5.0.v20100521-1846.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\org.eclipse.
bpmn2\0.7.3\org.eclipse.bpmn2-0.7.3.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\remote\kie-services-remote\6.0.1.Final\kie-services-remote-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\remote\kie-services-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-services-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\java
x\jms\jms\1.1\jms-1.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\servlet\jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\2.3.6.Final\resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\reposit
ory\org\scannotation\scannotation\1.0.3\scannotation-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javassist\javassist\3.12.1.GA\javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.2.1\httpclient-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\net\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0
\jcip-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxb-provider\2.3.6.Final\resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jackson-provider\2.3.6.Final\resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\rep
ository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.9\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.9.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.9\jackson-xc-1.9.9.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-audit\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-audit-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\
jaxrs-api\2.3.6.Final\jaxrs-api-2.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jettison-provider\2.3.6.Final\resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.3.1\jettison-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\j
boss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-services-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-services-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-m2repo-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-m2repo-edito
r-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-m2repo-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-m2repo-editor-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-m2repo-editor-backend\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-m2repo-editor-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\reposit
ory\org\guvnor\guvnor-project-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-project-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-workbench-models-datamodel-api\6.0.1.Final\drools-workbench-models-datamodel-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-project-backend\6.0.1.Fina
l\guvnor-project-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-services-backend\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-services-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-workingset-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-workingset-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository
\org\guvnor\guvnor-workingset-client\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-workingset-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-project-builder\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-project-builder-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C
:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-backend\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-api-6
.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project
-editor-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-editor-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-view-source-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-view-source-widget
-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-default-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-default-editor-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-default-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-default-editor-
client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-editor-backend\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-editor-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-
common-project-imports-editor-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-datamodel-
api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-datamodel-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-security\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-security-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-common-ui\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-ui-6.0.1.F
inal.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-workbench-models-commons\6.0.1.Final\drools-workbench-models-commons-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-datamodel-backend\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-datamodel-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\
AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-services-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-services-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-services-backend\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-services-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repo
sitory\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-metadata-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-metadata-widget-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-config-resource-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-config-resource-widget-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-conso
le-ng-dashboard-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-backend\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-api\6.0.1.Final\
jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-app\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-app-6.0.1.Final.war;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA
\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-backend\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbp
m-form-modeler-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-backend\6.0.1.Final\jb
pm-form-modeler-editor-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-core\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-core-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-form-provider\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-f
orm-provider-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-backend\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-
modeller-backend-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-client-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-data-modeler\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-data-modeler-
6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-service-core\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-service-core-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-common\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-common-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\net\sf\o
pencsv\opencsv\2.3\opencsv-2.3.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\commons-jxpath\commons-jxpath\1.3\commons-jxpath-1.3.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\beanshell\bsh\1.3.0\bsh-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\servlet\jsp\jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-jsp-ap
i_2.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-m2repo-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-m2repo-editor-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-m2repo-editor-client\6.0.1.Final
\guvnor-m2repo-editor-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-workingset-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-workingset-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-workingset-client\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-workingset-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar
;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-services-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-services-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\guvnor\guvnor-project-api\6.0.1.Final\guvnor-project-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-comm
on-project-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-editor-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-editor-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workben
ch\screens\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-imports-editor-client-6.0.1.Final-sou
rces.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-project-explorer-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-project-e
xplorer-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-common-ui\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-ui-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-view-source-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-view-source-widget-6.0.1.Final-sou
rces.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-metadata-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-metadata-widget-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\widgets\kie-wb-config-resource-widget\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-config-resource-widget-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C
:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-services-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-services-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-security\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-security-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\
.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\services\kie-wb-common-datamodel-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-datamodel-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\A
KILA\.m2\repository\org\kie\workbench\screens\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-client\6.0.1.Final\kie-wb-common-data-modeller-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-commons\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-commons-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\u
berfire\uberfire-nio2-model\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-nio2-model-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-js\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-js-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-security-api\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-security-api-0.3.1.Final-so
urces.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-security-client\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-security-client-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-client-api\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-client-api-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire
\uberfire-widgets-core-client\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-widgets-core-client-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-widgets-commons\0.3.1.Final\uberfire-widgets-commons-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\uberfire\uberfire-workbench\0.3.1.Final\ub
erfire-workbench-0.3.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-bpm-home-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-bpm-home-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-api-6.0.1
.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-process-runtime-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-process-runtime-api-6.0.1.Final-s
ources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-process-runtime-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-process-runtime-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-api-6.0.1.Final-s
ources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-designer-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-designer-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\reposi
tory\org\jbpm\jbpm-designer-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-designer-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-client\6
.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-dashboard-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-editor-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modele
r-editor-client-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-api\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-api-6.0.1.Final-sources.jar;C:\Users\AKILA\.m2\repository\org\jbpm\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-client\6.0.1.Final\jbpm-form-modeler-renderer-client-6.0.
1.Final-sources.jar, com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler, -logLevel, INFO, -style, OBF, -war, C:\Users\AKILA\workspace\jbpm-console-ng-r6.0.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-showcase\target\jbpm-console-ng-showcase-6.0.1.Final, -localWorkers, 4, -XfragmentCount, -1, -gen, C:\Users\AKILA\workspace\jbpm-console-ng-r6.0
.1.Final\jbpm-console-ng-showcase\target\.generated, org.jbpm.console.ng.FastCompiledjBPMShowcase]: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

---

please help me to resolve this problem
and i saw some people said this project working properly in linux platform...but i want to use it in windows platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a maven issue with long paths in windows, you need to ask in their forums for answer. Try googling the specific issues, you will find some answers there.

Comment: yes .. afterthat i did in fedora and it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to gradle project , It can be built under win7+gradle2.0+jdk 1.7.51 .